# Can anyone help caching process in webapps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, client, client-server

I had develop a web application (Still not published). It has many performance problem. So I decide cache my static assets into client's browser.

I have two static assets they are **app1.js** and **app2.js** (For example).

I would want to cache these assests. So I did add headers for these assest's response that is **Cache-Control : max-age=600**. Now I had 10 minutes cache of these files. It's working  very well.

But one problem is occured. The problem is, If I change my static assets within the **10 minutes** my changes not appeard in client. I know my caching process is reason for that. But I want when I change these assets suddenly these changes will update to clients with **Cache-Control : max-age=600** header.

At the same time If my changes has occuer only **app1.js** that only update to client. Not affect the **app2.js**.

Is there any way to done this? You know detail about caching, please share with me.

Thanks in Advance!

Vasikaran S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add fragment to the resource request when you update it. So `<script src="app1.js">` becomes `<script src="app1.js?v=4">`

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.